# Frontend REST API insert custom post type and assign custom taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, api, frontend, assign

I'm using the method from this [tutorial](https://apppresser.com/wp-api-post-submission/) and it works well for creating custom posts (sugestie) in frontend.

The problem is that i can't find a way to assign a custom taxonomy to those posts when the form is submitted. In backend it works well.

This is the taxonomy

```
register_taxonomy(  
    'cat_sugestie',  //The name of the taxonomy. 
    'sugestie', //post type name
    array(  
        'labels' => array(
            'name'              => _x( 'Categorii', 'taxonomy general name', 'books' ),
            'singular_name'     => _x( 'Categorie', 'taxonomy singular name', 'books' ),
            'search_items'      => __( 'Cauta Categorii', 'books' ),
            'all_items'         => __( 'Toate Categoriile', 'books' ),
            'parent_item'       => __( 'Categorie parinte', 'books' ),
            'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Categorie parinte:', 'books' ),
            'edit_item'         => __( 'Editeaza Categorie', 'books' ),
            'update_item'       => __( 'Update Categorie', 'books' ),
            'add_new_item'      => __( 'Adauga Categorie', 'books' ),
            'new_item_name'     => __( 'Numele noii Categorii', 'books' ),
            'menu_name'         => __( 'Categorii', 'books' ),
        ),  //Display name
        'hierarchical' => true,  
        'query_var' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'rest_base' => 'cat_sugestie',
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'cat_sugestie', // base slug that will display before each term
            'with_front' => false // display the category base before 
        ),
        'capabilities' => array(
            'assign_terms' => 'read',
        )
    )  
);
```

This is how i get the taxonomies in form

```
<div>
    <label for="post-submission-cat">
        <?php _e( 'Chose a category', 'your-text-domain' ); ?>
    </label>

    <select name="post-submission-cat" id="post-submission-cat">

    <?php if ($cats = get_terms(array('taxonomy' => 'cat_sugestie', 'hide_empty' => false) ) ) {
        foreach ($cats as $cat) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $cat->term_id; ?>"><?php echo $cat->name; ?></option>
        <?php   
        }
    } ?>

    </select>
</div>
```

This is the js code for submitting the post

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function ( $ ) {
    $( '#post-submission-form' ).on( 'submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var title = $( '#post-submission-title' ).val();
        var content = $( '#post-submission-content' ).val();
        var cat = parseInt($('#post-submission-cat' ).val());

        var data = {
            title: title,
            content: content,
            post_type: 'sugestie',
            status: 'pending',
            //cat_sugestie: cat  - this doesn't work
        };

        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: POST_SUBMITTER.root + 'wp/v2/sugestie',
            data: data,
            beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader( 'X-WP-Nonce', POST_SUBMITTER.nonce );
            },
            success : function( response ) {
                alert( POST_SUBMITTER.success );
            },
            fail : function( response ) {
                alert( POST_SUBMITTER.failure );
            }
        });
    });
});
```

So is it possible to achieve this?
Thank you!

Comment: Did you get the answer?

Answer (score 0):

While add your post in backend using ajax code at that time you need to add this code in your file after adding post in database.

```
wp_set_post_terms($pppid, $post_channel, 'category');
```

Where `$pppid` is your `post_id` and `$post_channel` is your `category id` and `category` is your `custom taxonomy name`.

it will work for you.

Comment: The thing is that i can't get the post id with this method. So basically i need to make another ajax call to wp_set_post_terms() right after the post was inserted, if i can find the id..

Comment: Still can't solve this. Do you guys have other ideas ?